# Importing and using a library in android studio

Tags: android

I am using android studio to import this project called  https://github.com/Pixate/pixate-freestyle-android. However when I import it into android studio the folder under samples, freestyleshowcase doesnt seem to build. The other 2 samples buld correctly. There is a red circle around the java file with a J (error) but there is no error in the file itself. COuld someone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You are obviously missing some libraries but it is going to be hard for anyone to tell you which since we do not know the libraries the project needs.You can try `Build-->Rebuild Project` or `Build-->Clean Peoject` if it still doesn't work, close and open Android Studio.
If that doesn't work also then you have to go the hard way of identifying the libraries need by the project samples you imported and see if you have them.

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, you can try the Library Dependency option (using Maven) as demonstrated here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6BUcx9gGQ3o

That way, you won't have to manually edit the build.gradle file.

Comment: Its best to post the relevant details, so if the like changes (or the video is deleted) the info inst lost.